# Angular 4 StaticInjectorError

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, routes

I just started with Angualar and encountered a problem which I don't understand. At the moment I am implementing a navigation for my frontend. I have two components. A CarList Component which shows a List of Cars and a AddCarForm component to add cars to said list. I used to nest the form component to the list component. For better modular design I want to create a CarMgmt-Component which adds both the list and the form.
But when I change the navigation from my list component to my mgmt component, I get following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)
[AddCarFormComponent -> CarlistComponent]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)
[AddCarFormComponent -> CarlistComponent]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for CarlistComponent!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)
[AddCarFormComponent ->  CarlistComponent]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)
[AddCarFormComponent -> CarlistComponent]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for CarlistComponent!
```

Following Code used to Work:

carlist.component.html

```
... HTML for List
<h2>Auto hinzufügen</h2>
<app-add-car-form></app-add-car-form>
</div>
```

carlist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from '../Car';
import { CarService } from '../Car.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';
import { Guid } from '../Guid';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-carlist',
   templateUrl: './carlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carlist.component.css']
})
export class CarlistComponent implements OnInit {
  private result : Observable<Object>;
  private cars : Car[];

  onUpdateClick() {
    this.carservice.getCars().subscribe(result => this.cars = result);
  }

  public updateList(){
    this.onUpdateClick();
  }

  constructor(private carservice : CarService) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

add-car-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from'../Car';
import { Guid } from '../Guid';
import { Model } from '../Model';
import { CarService } from '../Car.service';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, 
Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { CarlistComponent } from '../carlist/carlist.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-car-form',
  templateUrl: './add-car-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-car-form.component.css']
})
export class AddCarFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private carservice : CarService, private carListComp : CarlistComponent ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }  
}
```

Now I added a new component named carmgmt with following html
carmgmt.component.html

```
<app-carlist></app-carlist>
<app-add-car-form></app-add-car-form>
```

and changed the routes in app.module.ts from

```
{ path: 'cars', component: CarlistComponent }
```

to

```
{ path: 'cars', component: CarmgmtComponent }
```

and removed

```
<app-add-car-form></app-add-car-form>
```

from carlist.component.html

I know the issue is the injected carlist component in the carform component. But why is it working when I nest the form inside the list and not when I have both components in the mgmt component?

I hope you understand my question. Sorry if my english is not well enough.

Thanks for any help

Comment: CarlistComponent is not a child of AddCarFormComponent. It doesn't belong to its injector and doesn't have access to its instance. Whatever you're trying to do, you need to do that in another way.

Comment: why are you injecting the `carListComp` in the other component's constructor ?

Comment: In the addcarform component I add a car to the database. I then want to call a method on the carlist component which calls the database and updates the list. 
If that is the wrong way to do, could you give me a pointer what to look for?